# Get all dates selected in date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I am using a jQuery datepicker plugin from [KelvinLuck](http://2008.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerMultiple.html). This date picker is a multi-select date picker. In the tutorial it shows how you can display the selected date to the console. The tutorial only shows one date at a time. I'd like to display all the dates that are selected when a date is picked. So technically an array of selected dates. Is there a way to do this? Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/855f0rte/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="date-pick"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $('.date-pick')
    .datePicker({
      createButton: false,
      displayClose: true,
      closeOnSelect: false,
      selectMultiple: true,
      inline: true,
    })
    .bind(
      'click',
      function() {
        $(this).dpDisplay();
        this.blur();
        return false;
      }
    )
    .bind(
      'dateSelected',
      function(e, selectedDate, $td, state) {
        console.log('You ' + (state ? '' : 'un') // wrap
          + 'selected ' + selectedDate);

      }
    )
    .bind(
      'dpClosed',
      function(e, selectedDates) {
        console.log('You closed the date picker and the ' // wrap
          + 'currently selected dates are:');
        console.log(selectedDates);
      }
    );
});
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far.

Comment: @SumnerEvans My code is the same exact code as the tutorial. I'm just trying to get all dates selected instead of one by one

Comment: Please put the code into your question. I don't want to have to read that tutorial just to find the code you are using.

Comment: @SumnerEvans I updated my question with a jsfiddle and the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://2008.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/documentation.html):

> `dpGetSelected( ) returns Array`
>   Gets a list of Dates currently selected by this datePicker. This will be an empty array if no dates are currently selected or NULL if there is no datePicker associated with the matched element.
>
> **Example:**
>   Will alert an empty array (as nothing is selected yet)
>
> ```
> $('.date-picker').datePicker();
> alert($('.date-picker').dpGetSelected());
> ```